# PHP file doesn't able to load CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am Android developer and I have no idea about how PHP works. However due to a project I need to get something done.

I have index.html file in root of project and some .css files under css folder and some .js files under js folder. I can see the HTML file without any problem when I load index.html file.

My Apache server is running, PHP is installed and I change index.html to index.php. However seems CSS and JS files doesn't get loaded -or be used- as I see contents without proper formatting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Template - Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="css/gsallpage.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid gsumbrella">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <span class="span12">
                    <ul class="inline pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="inline">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/GRAPHISOFT_logo_white.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MyCAD</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">components</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">gsx</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Talk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wiki</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Facebook/AC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Youtube/AC</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <a href="home.html"><img src="img/_logo_grey.png"></a>
                        <form class="form-inline pull-right">
                            <div class="input-append">
                                <input class="span5" id="inputIcon" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?"><button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>  
                </div>
.....
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking your browser's debug console, or looking at the server access/error logs to see what actually got requested/served when those css requests came in?

Comment: thanks Mark, my index.php file doesn't have any php related functions at the moment. It is still pure html but my expectation is to see HTML text. Am I right?

Comment: pretty much. you can shove any file you want through php, and unless it sees a `<?php` marker, will treat the file as output. that being said, even if php is just passing your html through verbatim, there's any number of other reasons it might not be working. e.g. a server-side rewrite that triggers off `.php` files but not .html

Comment: If you use Firefox, you could also install an extension called Firebug, to check if your css is properly loaded (network tab).

Comment: Mostly problem is with relative urls. Check on chrome: right click->inspect->network, red items can not be loaded